# Relative path in build.gradle differs between Windows and OS X

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

My project have a folder with the keystore file (file.keystore). This is the structure:

```
+---.gradle
|   \---2.2
|       \---taskArtifacts
+---.idea
|   +---copyright
|   \---libraries
+---app
|   +---build
|   |   +---generated
|   +---libs
|   \---src
|       +---androidTest
|       \---main
+---build
|   \---intermediates
|       \---dex-cache
+---gradle
|   \---wrapper
\---keystore
```

To use it in build.gradle I use this:

```
signingConfigs {
    project {
        keyAlias 'project'
        keyPassword 'blabla'
        storeFile file('keystore\\file.keystore')
        storePassword 'blabla'
    }
```

In windows everything is correct because it searches in:

/project/keystore/file.keystore

But in OS X it is searching in:

/project/app/keystore/file.keystore

How should I code in the build.gradle?

Comment: have you tried `storeFile file(rootProject.projectDir.absolutePath +  '\\keystore\\file.keystore')` ?

Comment: Try  storeFile file('../keystore/file.keystore')

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try

```
project {
    keyAlias 'project'
    keyPassword 'blabla'
    storeFile file('../keystore/file.keystore')
    storePassword 'blabla'
}
```

I think it was too late. But maybe this will help someone has the same problem.

Comment: *What* is too late?

Answer (score 22):

Use groovy String Interpolation `$rootDir` property.

```
project {
   ...     
   storeFile file("$rootDir\keystore\file.keystore")
   ...
}
```

note that it uses **"double quotation"**

Answer (score 1):

Linh Nguyen Vu is Correct!
Below the Test! the keyword is **Resolved:**
[image: Testing the Solution]