# Build.gradle storeFile file(path) on windows ok but on auto build system not work

Tags: gradle, android-studio-3.0

Hello guys : we trying to use auto build system.

On windows after calling "gradle assembleRelease" everything fine. But when i push commit for auto build system its always show error about wrong path to keystore file.

```
 signingConfigs {
        configRelease {
            keyAlias 'keyalias'
            keyPassword 'password'
            storeFile file("$rootDir\\key.keystore")
            storePassword 'password'
        }
    }
```

key.keystore in root folder and in app folder
i tried a lot of things but still get problems. 
Maybe someone can help me ? 
Tried this :

```
storeFile file('$rootDir/key.jks')
storeFile file('$rootDir/key.jks')
storeFile file('../key.jks')
storeFile file('app/key.jks')
storefile file('key.jks')
```

and not remember but something like rootDirectory.file()
everything failed with wrong path to key. 
I know only this builded on unix system. 
Any help ?

Also i tried everything from this SO post :
[Relative path in build.gradle differs between Windows and OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938548/relative-path-in-build-gradle-differs-between-windows-and-os-x)

**[UPD]**Somehow also they moved build to windows VM . But still same errors